# Best word for health problems

Tags: word-choice, nouns, word-usage, grammatical-number, medical

What is the best word for pain and health problems caused by a disease?

I want to use it as term for a collection of symptoms, that I gather.
For example: [*headache*, *stomachache*, *nausea*]
but without a diagnosis which disease caused it

In German I use the word *Beschwerden* for this. I checked different online translators, which gave these options:

*discomfort, afflictions, ailment, disorders, complaints* and *trouble*.

But I think *complaints* is mainly used when someone is disagreeing with something, right?

By the way, when should I use the plural form?

UPDATE:
I found these dictionary entries:
http://search.medicinenet.com/search/search_results/default.aspx?Searchwhat=1&query=complaints&I1=Search
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complaints?s=ts
http://www.merriam-webster.com/medlineplus/complaint
http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=19380

Does this mean I can still use complaints?

Comment: I think 'affliction' may well fit in  your context!!

Comment: Are you looking for "malaise"?

Answer (score 5):

"Symptoms" is probably the best and simplest word. You might get a more precise answer if you give an example of what you are trying to say.

And use the plural form if there is more than one symptom (both pain and vomiting, for example).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to terms that describe a medical illness it is **not good** to use words such as:

> discomfort, ailment, disorders, complaints and trouble

Affliction is OK. In my humble opinion a better way to describe it would be saying they're or you're `unwell` or `have a medical illness`. This way you dont divulge any medical confidentiality.

Its probably best to say`unwell` and if people ask "Whats wrong?", clarify with `its a medical illness`.

If confidentiality isn't relevant simply use `painful disease`.

Comment: Interessting point. But I'm not sure, if this will also cover my use case. I want to use it as term for a collection of symptoms, that I gather. For example: [headache, stomachache, nausea], but with no clear diagnosis which disease caused it

Comment: I edited my answer and I think the word `afflictions` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

*Complaints* may to lay ears connote whining self-pity, which I suspect is why posters so far have disliked it, but it carries no such connotation in [medical usage](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/chief+complaint); and indeed it fits the bill quite nicely, as the patient’s own subjective report of what all is wrong, why medical care is sought.

Use the plural when patient complains of more than one thing, as for instance occasional stuffiness *and* more persistent loss of the sense of smell (anosmia).

Answer (score 1):

[***symptomatology***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/symptomatology)

> symptomatology: the collective symptoms of a patient or disease

*Initial [**symptomatology**](http://www.njafp.org/sites/ethos.njafp.org/files/4Q01_0404115711.PDF) includes fever...*

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions: *trouble*, *ailment(s)*, *complaint(s)*, and *disorder(s)* are generic terms which cover a wide range of symptoms.

- [heart trouble](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=signs+of+%22heart+trouble%22&oq=signs+of+%22heart+trouble%22&gs_l=serp.12..0j0i20j0j0i22i30l7.2552.5554.0.8032.2.2.0.0.0.0.163.326.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..0.2.324.caNBiE_USNU)
- [heart complaint](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22heart+complaints%22&oq=%22heart+complaints%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i7i30l10.23314.37777.0.39038.26.26.0.0.0.0.183.3578.0j24.24.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..13.13.2027._e8M8z-8wSA)
- [heart disorders](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22heart+disorders%22&oq=%22heart+disorders%22&gs_l=serp.12..0l10.3000.3000.0.4737.1.1.0.0.0.0.171.171.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..0.1.169.zBDtqLTE26E)
- [heart ailment(s)](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22heart%20ailment%22&oq=%22heart%20ailment%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i7i30l10.3451.3451.0.5235.1.1.0.0.0.0.164.164.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..0.1.162.E7ZwQqF4LbA)

*Discomfort* is perhaps the mildest and least serious sounding medical term, while the other terms insinuate that the person suffering from the ailment/trouble/complaint/ disorder actually needs to seek medical assistance.